# Feynman's statement about the importance of basic science

Tags: physics, electromagnetism, technology

I remember reading in the line that Feynman saying if the best technicians were tasked to build a radio they would make longer and thicker cables and transfer message but it took a physicist to realize that one can manipulate the motion of electrons to generate radio waves which then could be used for communication. I am trying to find reference to it but don't seem to find it anywhere. Did Feynman said something similar and if so where can I find the statement?

Thanks